# jQuery not defined in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, referenceerror

I'm trying to run jQuery in my chrome extension, but I keep getting the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I'm trying to use jQuery in the `content_script.js`, but it seems that it is only loaded in the `background.js`

Is there some additional code that I need to add to my `background.js`, so that `content_script.js` can use jQuery?

### My Code

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Flip That Tab",

"description": "Flips a guitar tab on ultimate guitar",

"version": "1.0",

"author": "TyDyeTV",

"short_name": "Tab Flip",

"icons": { 
    "16":"img/guitar16.png", 
    "48":"img/guitar48.png", 
    "128":"img/guitar128.png" 
        },

"permissions": [
"activeTab"
],

"background": {
  "scripts": ["jquery-2.2.4.min.js", "background.js"],
  "persistent": false
            },

"browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Flip That Tab",
  "default_icon": "img/guitar.png"
                },

"manifest_version": 2

}
```

**background.js**

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "jquery-2.2.4.min"});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});

});
```

**content_script.js**

```
// Code to flip tab

function isMusicLine(line)
{
    var numDash = 0;
    for (i=0; i < line.length; i++) 
    {
        if(line[i] == '-') 
        {
            numDash += 1;
        }
    }
    if (numDash > 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}


function createMusic(line, myArray, tempArr)
{
    if(tempArr.length > 0)
    {
        for (i=0; i< tempArr.length; i++)
        {
            myArray.push(tempArr[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        myArray.push(line);
    }

    return myArray
}



var element = document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML;
var element = $("cont").text(finalDoc)
```

Comment: content scripts do not live in the same environment as the background scripts. You would need to `executeScript` for jQuery before doing your content_script.js

Comment: @PatrickEvans I tried running the script inside content_script but no success...

Comment: You didnt wait for it to load the script, loading resources isn't instantaneous. And my previous comment meant doing: `executeScript(null, {file: "jquery.js"})`  before your other one

Comment: @PatrickEvans like so or am I missing the point?

Comment: nevermind. I forgot to put .js on the jquery file... oh the hardships lol